# Is this malware, or what?

Tags: malware

I was minding my own business, working on a C# utility, when this popped up:

[image]

I was not trying to install anythiing; I binged "nent73jm.tmp" and found nada; does anybody know what this might be? Is it potentially nefarious, or harmless?

Comment: If you weren't installing anything and nothing is doing an "automatic update," I'd say it looks pretty suspicious. (You won't get a search engine result with the name; That'll be an automatically generated name by the installer.)

Comment: Makes me wonder if the same sort of thing has already installed when my internet connection was better than it apparently was at the time.

Answer (score 2):

Are you working on your company's machine? Most corporate machines are configured to install updates / software silently. However most of these wrapper over normal installers are badly written causing such errors.

I would suggest download [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and look at the actual installer. Copy it before it is deleted (mostly once you click OK) and just upload it to a multi AV scan site. That shoudl give you some idea if it is a malware or no.

Comment: No, this was my home computer; I don't do anything really geeky with it; except for doing development on it (asp.net, mostly) and obviously having dev tools, it's basically like your run-of-the-mill average user's machine.